# Syntax error while running vite create with npm

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm trying to create a react project using vite but I'm getting an error while running
`npm create vite@latest` I'm on a fresh new ubuntu, I've just created a directory, opened a terminal inside that directory then ran `sudo apt install npm` followed by `npm create vite@latest` but I'm getting this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Since my setup is new have I forgotten to install something?

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Comment: @tony19 v12.22.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a version of Node that `vite@latest` (currently Vite 3.x) no longer supports. Vite 3 [requires Node 14.18 or newer](https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html#node-js-support):

> #### Node.js Support
>
> Vite no longer supports Node.js 12 / 13 / 15, which reached its EOL. Node.js 14.18+ / 16+ is now required.

The solution is to install one of the supported Node versions on your machine, and retry the `npm create vite@latest` command afterward.